# Adding group foreign key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am new to MySQL, and I have been trying to make a database based on a medical schema. Everything is fine, except I am facing problems with adding "group foreign keys" in the personnel table (the attributes enclosed in square brackets[]) as show in the picture.

See image:
[image]

Here is my code for the personnel table inside MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE personnel(
    hospital_id INT,
    room_no INT,
    surname VARCHAR(255),
    position VARCHAR(255),
    shift VARCHAR(255),
    salary INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(hospital_id,room_no) REFERENCES ward(hospital_id,room_no)
);
```

When I run this code, it compiles fine with a green checkmark. However, it doesn't show any foreign keys in the schema navigation sidebar, instead it creates indexes for these attributes. (see picture).

Image:
[image: see image]

Comment: You cannot add foreign key like this. If you need to add multiple foreign keys , you have to add it individually. as ` FOREIGN KEY(hospital_id) REFERENCES ward(hospital_id), FOREIGN KEY(room_no) REFERENCES ward(room_no) .

Comment: @Rishni no, this is not correct, you can have multi-column foreign keys in mysql!

Comment: @Shadow do you have a solution to my problem?

Comment: Your statement works just fine when I try it out.

Comment: Please share more details. Are you facing any error message?